# My app is running on the simulator but not on the device

Tags: ios, xcode4, ipod-touch

I have a problem with that error :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
```

When I build and go, it run successfully on the simulator but not on the device, I try a simple new project, I try to run it on the device, it was ok, but this project didn't run because of that error, the full stack error is this :

```
Ld "/Users/imac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TopStation-cjwcuxabgkltqvdslykmwkeqvsee/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RM Unit Tests.app/RM Unit Tests" normal i386
    cd /Users/imac/Desktop/route-me-route-me-b07b654/MapView
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk -L/Users/imac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TopStation-cjwcuxabgkltqvdslykmwkeqvsee/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/imac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TopStation-cjwcuxabgkltqvdslykmwkeqvsee/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist "/Users/imac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TopStation-cjwcuxabgkltqvdslykmwkeqvsee/Build/Intermediates/MapView.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Unit Tests.build/Objects-normal/i386/RM Unit Tests.LinkFileList" -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 /Users/imac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TopStation-cjwcuxabgkltqvdslykmwkeqvsee/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libProj4.a -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework Foundation -lsqlite3 -framework QuartzCore -framework UIKit -o "/Users/imac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TopStation-cjwcuxabgkltqvdslykmwkeqvsee/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RM Unit Tests.app/RM Unit Tests"

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RMDBTileImage", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in RMTileImage.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I changed the build mode, so I have choosed the device(in my case i use an iPod 4.3.5), now I have an other error :

```
'FavoriteCities.app' was built for 'i386', but the device 'iPod (Imac)' requires 'armv7' or compatible architecture.
```

FavoriteCities is my application name, please help me to figure out what could be the problem causing all that.

Comment: i386 architecture is for the simulator.  Looks like you are still building for the sim, not the device.

Comment: Hi, i choosed the device, the first error is solved but now i have a new error, please take a look on my EDIT, thanx in advance:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change build architecture for device builds. It should have been armv6/7 by default for iOS app, but I guess you or something you did messed those settings up.

(In Xcode 4) select your project, go to Build Settings tab and make sure it looks like this:

[image]