# app is not running on device but runs in simulator

Tags: ios5

For some reason my app runs on the simulator but not the device.  I saw the following link [My app is running on the simulator but not on the device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308523/my-app-is-running-on-the-simulator-but-not-on-the-device) but I'm not sure what the build mode is and where to change it.  I tried Product->Build For->Testing.  Is that what they mean?  It's still not getting to the device.  The xcode log (up where you see compilation general status) says "Running  on  iPod" but it never appears there.  It seems like in that link that they are saying I can build for iPod but I don't see that option.  I have had other of my apps run on this iPod, but I'm not sure why this one is having difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like it's working now.  I saw this post [iOS App runs on simulator but not device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192108/ios-app-runs-on-simulator-but-not-device) and saw the comment about restarting xcode and the device.  I already did that but this time I decided to restart my mac too along with restarting my device.  Plus, when I logged into the mac, I waited for it to pass through all the itunes business it usually does (do you want to sync, etc) when it first starts and recognizes that my device is connected.  Then I started xcode and ran my app.  The app was successfully running on the device after that.  Before, nothing was showing up on the device except for the app icon remained on the screen.